# How can i open angular md-autocomplete programmatically?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I need to open angular material md-autocomplete dropdown list on a specific event. Is there any way to do this?

I've got md-autocomplete with basic setup similar to this http://codepen.io/paucaverba/pen/GpogPv?editors=101

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" class="autocompletedemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
```

```
  <md-autocomplete md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-min-length="0" placeholder="What is your favorite US state?">
    <md-item-template>
      <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>
      No matches found for "{{ctrl.searchText}}".
    </md-not-found>
  </md-autocomplete>
  <br>
        <button class="md-button md-raised"> open </button>
</form>
```

If i click on control itself it will open the dropdown list. And i want the same behavior when i click on the "open" button

Comment: Could you please provide more info? For example your code would probably help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've added code example

Answer (score 1):

Give `id="auto_complete_id"` attribute to your `md-autocomplete`

You could try something like this: (Tested. This ought to work. This will not work on codepen though, it will throw an error in console)

Error in console on codepen( `Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!` )

Test it on native browser.

**HTML:**

```
<button  ng-click=openAutocomplete()> Open </button>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.openAutocomplete=function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       angular.element('#auto_complete_id').find('input').focus();
   },0);
}
```

Comment: @Alex Sorry to know that. Is it focusing on the input box or not ?

Comment: @Alex I have updated the code. I am using the same logic in my application. It works. Should work for you as well. If not try updating your libraries.

Comment: This works for me, *if* I have not already focused the input before.  If I click on the input, click out of it, then run this code, it doesn't work.  If I just run this code it works.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

A simple modification to the autocompleteDirective and autocomepleteController to expose a directive attribute, something like **md-focus** and **md-blur** would allow consumer controllers to operate on those events

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer, but if someone should find this answer, the problem above is mainly one of selecting elements.

In the current example (given in the CodePen in the question) the whole thing seems to work if

```
angular.element('#testId').focus();
```

is changed to

```
document.querySelector('#testId').focus();
```

or even

```
document.getElementById('testId').focus();
```

This is due to limitations of jqLite, and (in my opinion) an assumption about jQuery style selector based lookups are available, instead of using the proper method when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are seeking is by changing button click code to

```
var elem = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#testId' ) );
elem.focus();
```

minimal and straight to purpose.

Regards